# Load modal popup with help links in address line

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to load modal popup with help links in address line. Nothing happens. Help me please)

Link in the address bar: `http://site.ru/?data-toggle=modal&data-target=#mobes`

```
<!-- link-->
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mobes">link</a>
<!-- modal popup-->
<div class="modal fade" id="mobes" tabindex="2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<h2>Mobes</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<center>
...My text..
</center>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's your bootstrap version ?

Answer (score 0):

As i see this an external URL, so this URL will not be loaded. You will see the cross-origin access error in console. Alternative: You can use an iframe. 
Created **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2Fcd/712/)** for you.
For ex:

```
$(".modal-body").html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" src="'+url+'"></iframe>');
```